# Quagga ebgp routes not advertised to ibgp peers

Tags: networking, routing

I am trying to achieve http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/13762-40.html#conf3. Only difference from the setting is that the ISP is **sending full BGP table** instead of **the default gateway**. I have a problem that r101 won't advertise external routes to r102, which causes problem when r102's upstream peer disconnects and r102 looses all routes.

My configuration:

R101 running config:

```
router bgp 6001
 no synchronization
 bgp router-id 1.1.2.253
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 1.1.1.0
 network 1.1.2.0
 neighbor 2.1.1.249 remote-as 6000
 neighbor 2.1.1.249 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 neighbor 2.1.1.249 prefix-list 3 in
 neighbor 2.1.1.249 route-map R1-DC-MAP out
 neighbor 1.1.2.254 remote-as 6001
 neighbor 1.1.2.254 next-hop-self
 neighbor 1.1.2.254 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 maximum-paths 2
 no auto-summary
!
ip prefix-list 1 seq 5 permit 1.1.1.0/24
ip prefix-list 2 seq 5 permit 1.1.2.0/24
ip prefix-list 3 seq 5 deny 1.1.1.0/23
ip prefix-list 3 seq 10 permit any
!
route-map R1-DC-MAP permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list 1
 set as-path prepend 6001 6001 6001
!
route-map R1-DC-MAP permit 20
 match ip address prefix-list 2
!
route-map R1-DC-MAP deny 200
!
ip route 1.1.1.0/24 null0
ip route 1.1.2.0/24 null0
```

R102 running config:

```
router bgp 6001
 no synchronization
 bgp router-id 1.1.2.254
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 1.1.1.0
 network 1.1.2.0
 neighbor 3.1.1.25 remote-as 6000
 neighbor 3.1.1.25 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 neighbor 3.1.1.25 prefix-list 3 in
 neighbor 3.1.1.25 route-map R2-SIX-MAP out
 neighbor 1.1.2.253 remote-as 6001
 neighbor 1.1.2.253 next-hop-self
 neighbor 1.1.2.253 soft-reconfiguration inbound
 maximum-paths 2
 no auto-summary
!
ip prefix-list 1 seq 5 permit 1.1.2.0/24
ip prefix-list 2 seq 5 permit 1.1.1.0/24
ip prefix-list 3 seq 5 deny 1.1.1.0/23
ip prefix-list 3 seq 10 permit any
!
route-map R2-SIX-MAP permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list 1
 set as-path prepend 6001 6001 6001
!
route-map R2-SIX-MAP permit 20
 match ip address prefix-list 2
!
route-map R2-SIX-MAP deny 30
 match ip address 1.1.1.0/23
!
route-map R2-SIX-MAP deny 200
!
ip route 1.1.1.0/24 null0
ip route 1.1.2.0/24 null0
!
ip forwarding
!
line vty
!
end
```

R101 interface list:

```
Interface vlan3 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.1.253/30 broadcast 1.1.1.255

Interface vlan4 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 2.1.1.253/29 broadcast 2.1.1.255

Interface vlan101 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.1.61/26 broadcast 1.1.1.63
  inet 1.1.1.1/32 broadcast 1.1.1.1

Interface vlan106 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.1.125/27 broadcast 1.1.1.127
  inet 1.1.1.97/32 broadcast 1.1.1.97

Interface vlan107 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.1.141/28 broadcast 1.1.1.143
  inet 1.1.1.129/28 broadcast 1.1.1.143 secondary

Interface vlan109 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.1.93/27 broadcast 1.1.1.95
  inet 1.1.1.65/32 broadcast 1.1.1.65
```

R102 interface configuration:

```
Interface vlan3 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.2.254/30 broadcast 1.1.2.255

Interface vlan4 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 3.1.1.29/29 broadcast 3.1.1.31

Interface vlan101 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.2.62/26 broadcast 1.1.2.63
  inet 1.1.2.1/32 broadcast 1.1.2.1

Interface vlan106 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.2.126/27 broadcast 1.1.2.127
  inet 1.1.2.97/32 broadcast 1.1.2.97

Interface vlan107 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.2.142/28 broadcast 1.1.2.143
  inet 1.1.2.129/28 broadcast 1.1.2.143 secondary

Interface vlan109 is up, line protocol detection is disabled
  inet 1.1.2.94/27 broadcast 1.1.2.95
  inet 1.1.2.65/32 broadcast 1.1.2.65
```

Advertisments are not working at all on R101, but I can see advertisments coming from R102. Communication with upstream ISP BGP peers works as expected and I am obtaining full BGP from them.

R101 advertisments

```
BGP table version is 0, local router ID is 1.1.2.253
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, = multipath,
              i internal, r RIB-failure, S Stale, R Removed
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
```

R101 received-routes:

```
BGP table version is 0, local router ID is 1.1.2.253
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, = multipath,
              i internal, r RIB-failure, S Stale, R Removed
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 1.1.1.0     1.1.2.254           0    100      0 i
*> 1.1.2.0     1.1.2.254           0    100      0 i

Total number of prefixes 2
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? Any help appreciated.